# How to break line when using a Html.Raw?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to display a string from my model (in a StringBuilder) to my view.

The model:

```
mystring.Append("Some text... <br/> more text.");
```

The view:

```
@Html.Raw(Model.MyModel);
```

How can I actually break line inside that Html.Raw?
Keeping Html.Raw is mandatory.

Comment: Can you please try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560585/html-encode-but-preserve-line-breaks)

Answer (score 0):

You can break the line by using the `AppendLine()` method.

**Model:**

```
System.Text.StringBuilder mystring = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
mystring.AppendLine("Some text...");
mystring.AppendLine("</br>more text.");
```

**View:**

```
@Html.Raw(Model.MyModel);
```

Comment: Hello @FranciscoRibeiro, I edited my answer. Can you please check that?

Comment: Hi, @HarviPatel the problem is I need to show this code in a Google Chart. My stringbuilder is created like:
stringbuilder sb = new stringbuilder("['' , ''],")
When I try to appendLine to it the graph does not even get displayed. I'm trying to figure out why for weeks now. Any idea?

Comment: Hello @FranciscoRibeiro, Can you put exactly what you want to display using string builder here?

Comment: can you please see more detail in my post over GitHub? https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2922#issue-945262876